# Can php detect if an image has comments or not?

Tags: php

Preferably without installing any extensions as GD or imgick.

How can I check if a jpg has comments / headers or not ?

```
function hascomments($imgpath) {

}
```

I don't need to change comments or strip them out. I only want to know whether it has comments or not. As the images i'm expecting them to be uploaded through my c# app always doesn't have any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You will need to use the [`exif_read_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function.

```
$comments = exif_read_data('test.jpg', 'COMMENT')
```

This will extract the COMMENT [section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) of your image. If `$comments` is `FALSE` then the section does not exist.

Comment: is comment the same as header? what if I use IFD0 instead of COMMENT. I saw that somewhere in the link you provided ?

Comment: The docs say that `IFD0` is different than `COMMENT`. However, `IFD0` does contain a `UserComment` field, but this is not the same as the JPG comment headers

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [exif_read_data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php), might be able to sort you out.

What you would like to use is,

```
exif_read_data ( string $filename, string $sections );
```

Where putting `$sections` to `COMMENT` would return to you the comment header of the JPEG image, or `false` if it does not exist.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Since it was neither a critique nor a request of clarification, and it provides the function which is the answer to the questions I assume you mean to say that it was the right place to put it @Bongs? :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bobs, that is critique I can understand, thank you for your input :)